# Program won't display first line of text when inside for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have been trying to display the first line of a text file. This worked when I used the `readline()` function but when I use the readline function inside a for loop it displays nothing? I tried to use the readline function outside the loop and it worked perfectly

```
AAreasons1 = open("10,000 Reasons.txt", "r") 
alive = open("Alive.txt", "r")
alldays = open("All of My Days.txt", "r")
listsong = [AAreasons1,alive,alldays]
for song in listsong:
    song1 = song.read()
    song2 = (song1.lower())
    print(song.readline())
    song.close()
```

additionally these are the first lines of each txt file

```
10,000 Reasons.txt - "10,000 Reasons"  
Alive.txt - "Alive"  
All of My Days.txt - "All of My Days"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.read()` on a file object, it reads and exhausts it completely.

You can either do `song.seek(0)` to go back to the beginning and then call `song.readline()`, or you can just take the first line: `song1.split("\n")[0]`.

Comment: Solved! Thankyou!  
On a side note it seems that there is space printed below the first line

Comment: is there anyway to get rid of that?

Comment: Every line ends with a newline character. To get rid of it, call `.strip()` on your line.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in logic.

using this

> song.read()

you have read all the file. So the header for reading file is at end of the file.
Now when you use

> song.readline()

it prints nothing.

To get rid of this, before using readline() make the header point again to start of the file using

> song.seek(0,0)